# get a right sum of a columns ( coldfusion )

Tags: sql, coldfusion, row, sum

I have a table with products listed by month, i found row sum of them, and i need to find column sum, but my counts are wrong for column sums, what am i doing wrong? u can have a look at the code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/KRHbx/ thank you everyone for your help! ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here, you're referring to p_index outside of the loop that increments p_index.  So it's always going to be referring to the last element of your product_id_list.

```
<cfif isdefined('total2_#kk#_#p_index#') and evaluate('total2_#kk#_#p_index#') neq 0>
                        <cfset satis_oran= evaluate('total2_#kk#_#p_index#')>
```

Comment: yeah, I know, but once i add there the loop of products, it loops a lot of irrelevant data...